# Export Gridview into CSV File using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, gridview

I am trying to export the gridview data into csv file but when i export the file, i am getting this in the 2nd column always

```
<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>P<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>l<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>a<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>t<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>e<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>l<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>e<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>t<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span> <span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>F<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>u<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>n<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>c<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>t<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>i<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>o<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>n<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span> <span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>A<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>n<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>a<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>l<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>y<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>z<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>e<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>r<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>s<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'></span>
```

the rest of the columns are good but the issue is always with the 2nd column.
here is my code:

```
protected void btnExportCSV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=gvtocsv.csv");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/text";
    StringBuilder sBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < gvSearch.Columns.Count; index++)
    {
        sBuilder.Append(gvSearch.Columns[index].HeaderText + ',');
    }
    sBuilder.Append("\r\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < gvSearch.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < gvSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; k++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(gvSearch.Rows[i].Cells[k].Text.Replace(",", "") + ",");
        }
        sBuilder.Append("\r\n");
    }
    Response.Output.Write(sBuilder.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: What type of data is there in 2nd column of gridview

Comment: it is varchar(30)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some formatting on that column?

```html
<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
P<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
l<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
a<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
t<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
e<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
l<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
e<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
t<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
 <span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
F<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
u<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
n<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
c<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
t<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
i<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
o<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
n<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
 <span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
A<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
n<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
a<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
l<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
y<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
z<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
e<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
r<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
s<span style = 'background-color:#00ff00'/>
```

I see Platelet Function Analyzers

Comment: i don't have any formatting on the 2nd column:  <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" HtmlEncode="true" SortExpression="contract_name" />

Comment: Just to clarify when you say the issue is always with the 2nd column, are you talking about the 2nd word generated from the grid.  Unless I am misinterpreting this, I thought you were trying to get this effect, if so wont you will need &nbsp; surely for the spaces?

https://jsfiddle.net/5o3gzahq/